# Generic method that returns subclass of explicitly declared superclass

Tags: java, generics

**The Goal**

The title is long and confusing... I want a method which can be used like this:

```
Double d = getAsNumber(Double.MAX_VALUE);
Short s = getAsNumber(Short.MAX_VALUE);
```

- The method is guaranteed to only accept a subclass of java.lang.Number
- The method will only return an instance of the exact same class that was passed in

The parameter being passed in is actually a default value in case the getAsNumber method doesn't actually have a value.

**What I have so far**

This is actually working but it's ugly and I don't understand why the heck I need to explicitly cast with (T). The enum feels like an ugly workaround, and (T) shouldn't be necessary, the compiler KNOWS that Double or Long is a subclass of Number...

```
 private enum NUMBER_CLASS {
        Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short
    }

    private static final <T extends Number> T  getAsNumber( T defaultVal ) {
        final String string = "2";//would normally get from data source
        if (string==null) {
            return defaultVal;
        }

        NUMBER_CLASS numberClass = NUMBER_CLASS.Double.valueOf(defaultVal.getClass().getSimpleName());
        switch (numberClass) {
            case Double:
                return (T) Double.valueOf(string); // WHY is explicit cast necessary!
            case Long:
                return (T) Long.valueOf(string);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must give a java.lang.Number");
        }
    }
```

**There must be a better way?**

** **UPDATE** **

Multiple questions are posed here. The main question I'm actually after is why I needed to explicitly cast with (T). It seems to me the compiler has all of the information it needs in order to guarantee that Double will meet the method signature's return type.

Comment: There isn't going to be a significantly better way.  Generalizing over `Number` types in Java is ~inevitably doomed to failure.  (And trying to do what you're trying to do with switching over classes is also going to be inevitably as awkward as you have it.)

Comment: That's fair, and I admit I'm asking multiple questions... There's a priority question here for me, though - WHY did I need the explicit cast? This is learning for me I guess. I'll update the question.

Comment: There is _no_ mechanism in Java for the compiler to figure out that you've "proved" `T` is any particular type.  That's just not a thing Java's type system knows how to do.

Comment: Then what is the value in me typing "<T extends Number>" ? Did that not say that the return instance will be instance of Number? We know that the compiler can test that Double is subclass of Number - it does that type of testing constantly.

Comment: You can't tell the compiler that you've figured out *which* subclass of Number T is.

Comment: Don't use standard class names as identifiers, especially `java.lang` class names, because it's confusing and anyway violates the Java naming conventions. Your enum class name also violates the naming conventions. Also, using your enum constant `Double` to retrieve data for other enum constants is weird and unlikely to work well. Believe it or not following the conventions helps prevent bugs.

Comment: @LewBloch ehh, I've been a pretty strong advocate of naming conventions over my career, but I'm trying to clarify my understanding of compile-time processing and not looking to argue about the dogma of naming convention

Comment: I don't see that there is any room for argument or offer of such, nor is there any dogma being promoted, just good engineering sense. If you name your constants or variables the same as standard types like `Double`, you're begging for technical trouble. But I am not here to argue, only to offer sensible advice, which of course you're free to ignore to your own detriment.

Comment: @LewBloch I agree with 100% of your advise. It is the same advise I've already given myself on this code. That's why I called it an "ugly workaround." But, it's irrelevant to my question at hand. There won't be any detriment as I'm not ignoring anything sensible here. I have an enum that *purposely* breaks a convention because it's the only way to accomplish this hack, which I found as the only solution from a separate stackoverflow thread. It seems sort of like you _are_ here to argue.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is unable to find what is your function internal reasoning. Imagine the code:

```
switch (numberClass) {
    case Double:
        return Long.valueOf(string); // If there is no cast it will broke type system
    case Long:
        return Double.valueOf(string); // The same
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must give a java.lang.Number");
}
```

The return value isn't formally connected to the type `T` so without the cast it's possible to return `Long` with `Double` argument, etc. That's why the cast is needed.